# SUM for expression field in RTF BI Publisher

Tags: rtf, bi-publisher

currently, I got some problem in doing my RTF Template.

[image]

the units field, im using expression
'<?xdofx:if UNITSINCURRENTRUN = 0
Then UNITSINCURRENTRUN
else if UNITSIN is null then 0
Else UNITSIN
end if?>'

the problem is, when i want to make the grand total below the units field. I cant get the correct value for the sum.

Anyone care for help?

Thank you

already tried using <choose><otherwise> function but still not succeed

Comment: Can you provide some sample data XML and what you are expecting as an end result?